# RetryTemplate for specific exceptions not triggered

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am implementing a retry logic  using the spring retry template that needs to retry 3 times for 2 types of exceptions that are anticipated to occur on API invocation using the rest template. I am not seeing it triggered for some reason.

Here is my RetryTemplate Configruation

```
    @Bean(name="myRetryTemplate")
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicyCheck1 = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicyCheck2 = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicyCheck1.setMaxAttempts(3);
        simpleRetryPolicyCheck2.setMaxAttempts(3);
        
        final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, RetryPolicy> policyMap = new HashMap<>();
        policyMap.put(Exception1.class, simpleRetryPolicyCheck1 );
        policyMap.put(Exception2.class, simpleRetryPolicyCheck2 );
        
        final ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setPolicyMap(policyMap);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        
        return retryTemplate;
    }
```

Here is my Service call:

```
public Object getSomething(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
        return retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Object, Exception>() {
            @Override
            public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext arg0) {
                Object o = restTutorialClient.getEmployeesList(id);
                return o;
            }
        });
```

I  can see the simulated Exception type 1 thrown. But there is no retry happening. Please guide to know where is this failing and the corrective measures?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the constructor of the class SimpleRetryPolicy which takes two parameters, the number of attempts and the list of exceptions like this :

```
Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put(Exception1.class, Boolean.TRUE);
map.put(Exception1.class, Boolean.TRUE);
SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3 , map);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't need a custom retry policy or custom back-off policy, you can use the annotation [@Retryable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html) :

```
    @Component
    public class RetryableAction {

        @Autowired
        private RestTutorialClient restTutorialClient;

        @Retryable(value = {
            Exception1.class,
            Exception2.class
        }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
        Object retryAction(String id) throws Exception1, Exception2 {
            return restTutorialClient.getEmployeesList(id);

        }
    }

    @Service
    public class ServiceResource {

        @Autowired
        private RetryableAction retryableAction;

        @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
        public Object getSomething(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
            Object object = retryableAction.retryAction(id);
            // Business logic
        }
```

***EDIT :*** Since you want to perform retries for both exceptions 3 times then, I suggest to have a super exception class which will have two children Exception1 and Exception2 :

```
    @Component
    public class RetryableAction {

        @Autowired
        private RestTutorialClient restTutorialClient;

        @Retryable(value = SuperException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
        Object retryAction(String id) throws SuperException {
            return restTutorialClient.getEmployeesList(id);

        }
    }

    @Service
    public class ServiceResource {

        @Autowired
        private RetryableAction retryableAction;

        @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
        public Object getSomething(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
            Object object = retryableAction.retryAction(id);
            // Business logic
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am aware of  sing the @Retryable annotation. But I am looking for  implementing the same using retryTemplate  where  I can specify retry logic and  delays each for indiviual exception.  In case I want to  re try 3 times for each occurence of Exception1 and 2, how can this bedone. Let me give an example:

1. Exception 1 occured and on retry attempt 1 - exception 2 occurs. Now for the occured excetion  Retryable will not try only for 2 more times. Is my understanding right as maxAttempts is 3 and 1 is already exhausted. But I want Spring to try for 3 times for exception 2 as well

Comment: Yes, I got your point. In this case, whether you use the annotation Retryable or the RetryTemplate. You will get the same result since when you define the list of exceptions to be handled, you will never retry for each exception. If the total number of retries exceeds the maxAttempts, this will ends the process. 
However, I’m thinking about a solution where you define two method which do the same stuff but annotated with retryable for each exception. Or a second solution where you catch a super type exception of your exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @M.Mas. Here is what i am missing. Are you saying that even though I define  separate RetryPolicy for Exception 1 and 2, will that not work?

Comment: Please see my  code edited. I have added simpleRetryPolicyCheck1/2 for Exception 1/2. Will this not make it try 3 times  each per occurence?

Comment: You can try it but I'm not sure that it will work since there is a class in spring-retry  ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy which let you configure different retry behavior for an arbitrary set of exception types though the ExceptionClassifier abstraction. Take a look at this https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/policy/ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy.html